# I use Google Analytics in Flutter already, how can I also send events to it from native iOS/Android code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I use firebase for flutter, where all the dependencies are on pubspec.yaml
I would like to send an event to Firebase Analytics for some activities on the native side - Home screen widget, notification received, etc.

Is it possible?
FirebaseAnalytics class is not recognized on Android and if I add it to gradle, it might collide with flutter.

Comment: Do you have one flutter app and another native android/ios app? You can achieve that by simply adding another android/ios app to the project. As you will add different config file for your project , it will log events differently under the app. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: @Fahmida It's a single app with a wide native layer containing native iOS/Android widgets, location tracking, background push, deep linking, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PlatformChannel` is a solution for this case, see [platform-channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).
Example code (original code from [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter):

- Android side:

```java
package com.example.shared;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  private static final String CHANNEL = "app.channel.shared.data";
  private String sharedText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    sharedText = "Home screen displayed";
  }

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

      new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
              .setMethodCallHandler(
                      (call, result) -> {
                          if (call.method.contentEquals("onScreenView")) {
                              result.success(sharedText);
                              sharedText = null;
                          }
                      }
              );
  }

}
```

- Flutter side:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const SampleApp());
}

class SampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample Shared App Handler',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SampleAppPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SampleAppPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleAppPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SampleAppPage> createState() => _SampleAppPageState();
}

class _SampleAppPageState extends State<SampleAppPage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('app.channel.shared.data');
  String dataShared = 'No data';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSharedText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text(dataShared)));
  }

  Future<void> getSharedText() async {
    var sharedData = await platform.invokeMethod('onNotificationClicked');
    if (sharedData != null) {
      setState(() {
        dataShared = sharedData;

        // Send data to Firebase Analytics here
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But the main activity is not running - I would like to know that the device receives a silent push, for example.

It can be implemented with some persistent events queue that is fetched when flutter is available, but I'm looking for something more elegant, like playing with the includes on the native side, or use one of firebase internals to figure this out.